Fourier transform of $\frac{e^{-|x|}}{\sqrt{|x|}}$
Please help me find Fourier Transform for $f(x) = \frac{e^{-|x|}}{\sqrt{|x|}}$
What I have now:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}}{f(x)e^{-ixy}~dx} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{-x}\cos(xy)}{\sqrt{x}}}~dx = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\operatorname{Re}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{ixy-x}}{\sqrt{x}}}~dx\right)$$
I'm stuck on this and do not know what to do next, any help would be greatly appreciated!

If $x=u^2,$ the integrand becomes $2e^{-u^2(1-yi)}.$ Not sure where to go from there.

The Fourier Transform is $\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{y^2+1}+1}{y^2+1}}$

@MarkViola, wow! and how can we get it?

@JohnDoe I've posted a solution herein.

@johndoe Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

We begin by folding the integral and enforcing the substitution $x\mapsto x^2$.  This reveals that
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-|x|}}{\sqrt{|x|}}e^{-ixy}\,dx&=2\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt x}\,\cos(xy)\,dx\\\\
&=2\text{Re}\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-(1-iy)x}}{\sqrt x}\,dx\right)\\\\
&=4\text{Re}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-\left(\sqrt{1-iy}\,x\right)^2}\,dx\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$
Next, we enforce the substitution $\sqrt{1-iy}\,x\mapsto x$ to obtain
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-|x|}}{\sqrt{|x|}}e^{-ixy}\,dx=4\text{Re}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1-iy}}\int_0^{\infty/\sqrt{1-iy}} e^{-x^2}\,dx\right)$$
Invoking Cauchy's Integral Theorem, we can deform the contour back onto the real line to find
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-|x|}}{\sqrt{|x|}}e^{-ixy}\,dx&=4\text{Re}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1-iy}}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx\right)\\\\
&=2\sqrt{\pi}\text{Re}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1-iy}}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{2\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\text{Re}\left(\sqrt{1+iy}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{2\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\text{Re}\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{1+y^2}e^{i\arctan(y)}}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{2\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{1+y^2}} \sqrt{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\cos(\arctan(y)/2)\\\\
&=\frac{2\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{1+y^2}} \sqrt{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(\arctan(y))}{2}}\\\\
&=\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{1+y^2}\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\right)}}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\\\\
&=\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1+y^2}+1}{1+y^2}}
\end{align}$$

Could you explain more in detail how you went from integrating the gaussian from the line $z=\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{1-iy}},\ t\in(0,\infty)$ to the real positive line? I thought about using $\displaystyle \oint_C e^{-z^2}dz=0$, but I didn't succeed. Then I saw you had found the solution and desisted.

@Conreu I stated that one can use Cauchy's Integral Theorem to justify the deformation.  What else do you need?

Well, I wanted to know what closed contour did you use in Cuachy's Thm? Most likely a triangle right?

Actually, we can use a "pie" shaped wedge.

Ooh, I see. That makes more sense since the integral along the arc of the contour would go to $0$ once $r\to\infty$ and therefore the integral along that complex line is minus the one along the real positive axis.

@Conreu Yes indeed.

@Semiclassical Yes indeed.  Good catch.  Thank you.  In fact, there was a copy and paste error that led to three occurences of $|x|$ instead of $\sqrt{|x|}$.  I've edited accordingly.

+1 $\mbox{}\mbox{}$

@FelixMarin Hi Felix.  Thank you my friend!  How are you?

@johndoe Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

@johndoe And feel free to upvote and accept an answer as you see fit.  ;-)

Just a little different approach. Recall that $g_\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ is a probability density for every $\sigma > 0$ and hence integrates to $1$. In other words, for any $u>0$ we have $$\int_0^\infty e^{-ux^2}dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 \cdot \frac{1}{2u}}}dx = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{u} }.$$ Now, note that both functions $F(z) = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{z}}$ and $G(z) = \int_0^\infty e^{-z x^2}dx$ are holomorphic on the plane $P = \{z \in \mathbb C : \Re(z) > 0\}$ and since they agree on $(0,\infty) \times \{0\} \subset P$, then $F=G$ on whole $P$ (identity theorem).
In particular, $$ \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{e^{-|x|}}{\sqrt{|x|}} e^{ixy}dx = 2 \Re \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x(1-iy)}}{\sqrt{x}} dx = 4\Re \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2(1-iy)}dx = 4\Re (G(1-iy)) = 4\Re( F(1-iy)) = 4\Re\left( \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1-iy}}\right).$$ What remains are algebraic manipulations, the same as in Mark Viola answer.

$$\int_{R}e^{-|x|+ix\tan \theta}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}=2\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{\cos \theta}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}.$$

For $|\theta|<\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have
$\int_{R}e^{-|x|+ix\tan \theta}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}=2\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{\cos \theta}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}.$
Proof. $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{\frac{1}{2}-1}dx=\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$ If $\Re z<1$ one has $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x+zx}x^{\frac{1}{2}-1}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}
{\sqrt{1-z}}$ (with the obvious determination). More generally if $\Re z\in (-1,1)$ we have $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|x|+zx}|x|^{\frac{1}{2}-1}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{1-z}}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{1+z}}=\sqrt{\pi}\frac{\sqrt{1+z}+\sqrt{1-z}}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$  Doing $z=i\tan\theta$ we get $
1+\pm i\tan \theta=\frac{e^{\pm \theta}}{\cos \theta}$,  $
\sqrt{1\pm i\tan \theta}=\frac{e^{\pm \theta/2}}{\sqrt{\cos \theta}}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan ^2\theta}}=\cos \theta.$
Something wrong?
